# Importing localized content to Civicrm database

Tags: data-import

I have tried to use the import process in civicrm for importing my urdu data fields into civicrm. After I map the fields in my csv to fields available in civicrm db i get error file. I am attaching the image from my error file.[image: import error file]

Please note that the data is in urdu. I want civicrm to display the data in its fields like first name will contain the name of my contact in urdu.

My import verification came like this
[image]

I appreciate any help from the community.

Comment: I don't think it's related to language it seems more like you don't have any of the required fields? You need either a column heading for Last Name or Email.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have again attached my data verification screen shot. pls have a look.

Comment: In the right-hand column there one of the fields needs to be either Last Name or Email. So on the screen before that where you choose the fields, try it with "Last Name" instead of where you picked "First Name".

Answer (score 1):

You need to have (first name and last name)  or (email) columns not empty data. Also make sure your csv has character set to Unicode UTF-8 and is separated with correct delimeters

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, CiviCRM either wants a first and last name or an email address.  You appear to have just a single name field and no emails.

I'm not familiar with naming in Urdu. Can you split the name into two parts and create a 'first name' and 'last name' field?  Does that make any sense for Urdu names?

If not, you will need a workaround either by creating a fake last name or email for everyone.

Longer term, it would be worth raising the question as to whether the current requirements are appropriate for global usage. I don't see any intrinsic reason why those requirements could not be relaxed.